# Adding separator characters in each cell of a column

Tags: vba

I have column A which contains numbers, I would like to add the character "-" every 9 lines while a "*" every 10 for the entire length of column A which can vary and can it be done ?? Thank you

```
Sub Copia()

Dim lrow_copy As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long

lrow_copy = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 

i = 1 


For j = 1 To lrow_copy Step 1 
    Sheets(2).Range(Sheets(2).Cells(j, "A"), Sheets(2).Cells(j + lrow_copy, "A")).copy 
    Sheets(2).Range(Sheets(2).Cells(i, 3), Sheets(2).Cells(i, 3)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues  'Paste range and transpose the copied range
    
   i = i + 1 & "-" 

Next j

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code attempt, and example of the data + desired output.

Comment: 1. Please, show us what you tried by your own. 2. Nothing is clear in your question. I tried reading it three times and I cannot understand what you want. I am not a native English speaker and this may be a bad circumstance, but if you need help from such people, too, please edit your question and better clarify what you want doing. A picture showing the initial situation and another one showing what you need may help, I think.

Comment: Your code does not clarify the question, I am afraid. ` i = i + 1 & "-" ` will always return `i = 2-". In the way you use it, the variable is not number any more. But why do you need it? What does "while a "*" every 10 for the entire length" mean?

Comment: the values ​​shown in column A are subsequently copied with transposition in a table, this has 8 rows and 8 columns, I would like to separate each single value with a stroke to have a distinct view

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the original data and a screenshot of the desired output. It's difficult to help you with so many missing information.

Comment: So, do you like to firstly copy the range "A1:A8" transposed in "C1"? And secondly, to copy "A8:A16", or "A2:A9" in "C2"? Then, please make another effort and translate what "I would like to separate each single value with a stroke" should mean? Don't you wan to transpose that range and, in fact, you **want a string of these 8 cells value, separated by "|" character**?

Comment: So, no any transpose need, nothing to do with "*", you want placing a "-" character to the end of first 7 rows and the following one without and repeat this procedure up to the column end?

Comment: Can you confirm that my supposition is correct? If not understanding what I mean, please test the third code variant of my answer and send some feedback. I still suppose you need help... Am I wrong?

Comment: Does the picture you show us contain the existing situation to the left and the desired one to the right? Can you confirm this? If not, what does it represent?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub testMarkerAtTheEnd()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long, j As Long, arr
  Set sh = Sheets(2)
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  arr = sh.Range("A1:A" & lastR).value
  i = 1
  For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
     If i > 1 Then arr(j, 1) = arr(j, 1) & "-"
     i = i + 1
     If i = 8 Then i = 1
  Next j
  sh.Range("C1").Resize(UBound(arr), 1).value = arr
End Sub
```